# Create a launchpad button that opens the content and makes the current context a specific folder

Tags: content-editor, launchpad

I'm able to add a launchpad button that opens the content editor, but what I would like to do is to open the content editor so that it's context is within a specific folder - so the user doesn't see anything but items in that folder.

If not that, then simply opening it so that the user at least sees that folder prominently so they don't need to hunt for it - the folder is in the media library and will contain training documents we are preparing that will help them maneuver the CMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query string parameter you want is called `ro`. If you click on the `Media Library` folder you will see that it uses that param to scope the content editor like this:

`https://mysitecore.local/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/Default.aspx?mo&ro=/sitecore/media%20library&he=Media%20Library&ic=Apps/32x32/Pictures.png&pa=1&pa0=sitecore%3A%2F%2Fmaster%2F%7BECB7C485-63A6-4627-9DD9-D9FDA86D9DB5%7D%3Flang%3Den%26ver%3D1&pa1&sc_bw=1&la=en`

You can see in the above url that the `ro` parameter is set like this:

```
ro=/sitecore/media%20library
```

Changing that to

```
ro=/sitecore/media%20library/Project
```

Now scopes the Content Editor to the `Media Library/Project` folder just as you want.

[image]

#### Adding this to the Launch Pad

Now you can use this to add an icon in the launch pad:

- Open up the Desktop and change to the `core` database
- Open the Content Editor and go to: `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons` and then pick one of the sections (`LaunchPad-Group` template items) to add your button too
- I'll pick `Tools` - insert a new `LaunchPad-Button` item, and for the `Link` field, add the link from above with the `ro` parameter set to the item you want to scope the user too.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it! :-)

Comment: Oh yeah - ha ha. Great minds - pretty similar approaches :)

Comment: Thanks, I added the ro parameter to the link field and it worked right away!  I'm not sure though how you are seeing the long url's as you described - if mine did that I'd have figured this out already, but mine stays static at /Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1 regardless of what item I click on in the content tree...

Answer (score 5):

I may have found a way for you to do this with some trial and error.

First step was to get the path executed by the desktop shortcuts. Once I discovered that I was able to create the following in the Core db:

1. Navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons`
2. Create a new Launchpad-Group
3. Create a new Launchpad-Button

   - Enter the link to the item in question

[image: Button]

Here is the link used:

`/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1&id=%7B66FD3C09-517C-4691-82AF-E300AC6BA329%7D&amp;vs=1&amp;la=en&amp;sc_content=master&amp;fo=%7B66FD3C09-517C-4691-82AF-E300AC6BA329%7D&amp;ic=Apps%2F48x48%2FPencil.png&amp;he=Content%20Editor&amp;cl=0`

With some trial this appeared to work as well:

`/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1&fo={66FD3C09-517C-4691-82AF-E300AC6BA329}&ro={66FD3C09-517C-4691-82AF-E300AC6BA329}&sc_content=master`

- *fo* is the ID of the item to open
- *ro* is for the reference item in the tree

[image: Icon]